# Xamarin forms MasterDetailPage navigation use case

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, navigation, prism

Here is my scenario:

My app starts with opening a `MasterDetailPage`. The `Master` is a `StackLayout` of `Button` that just open a specific `DetailPage`. You can see this as some kind of video library with a Menu...

I want the hamburger menu to be available so the user can access the Master anytime and switch between videos.

I am using Prism 7.2, so the first navigation is set up this way in the App.xaml.cs file:

```
await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("MasterPage/NavigationPage/MainPage");
```

But then I want to avoid the possibility to navigate back after hitting a specific page. For me it makes no sens in this context for the user to go back to the `Master` this way. He should use the hamburger menu. So in that case, when hitting the back button, the app should just exit. To accomplish that I thought about rewriting the entire stack when I navigate to a `DetailPage`:

```
// Where page parameter is like "MasterPage/NavigationPage/VideoPage?...."
private async Task NavigateCommandAsync(string page)
{
    await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("myapp:///" + page);


    // Some of the things I've tried...
    //await NavigationService.GoBackAsync();
    //await NavigationService.NavigateAsync(page);

    //await NavigationService.NavigateAsync(new Uri(page, UriKind.Relative));
}
```

At least this way, when the user clicks the back button, it just exits the app which is what I wanted.

So far so good in therms of behavior. Except that I started to notice a white page binking before showing any DetailView. At the end, I've clearly understood that it was the NavigationPage that was shown for <1s. But this is annoying from a user experience point of view. Also I was able to change the BackgroundColor of this page so it looks less ugly but it's still not optimal...

Now I've tried many changes in therms of pushing the `DetailPage` but then the behavior is obviously not the same. So far I've understood, I need to wrap anyway the detail page in a NavigationPage in order to get the hamburger menu. But then this NavigationPage is binking all around. If I remove it, I lose the hamburger menu.

Is there any possible workaround for such a case using a `MasterDetailPage`? Or any idea of what am I doing wrong or misunderstood?